# Can't load the Samsung smart TV 5.1 IDE

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Hello and thanks for your time. When I open the eclipse.exe file and go to file > new > project there are no samsung options. I have tried running the eclipse.exe file as administrator but no luck. I should mention my normal login has admin privileges as well. I have also redownloaded and unziped the IDE a few times. I am running windows XP 32bit. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: ... Have you installed anything Samsung specific? Eclipse does not contain anything Samsung-related by default.

Comment: Yea when you download the IDE and unzip it the file is still just named eclipse.exe but it is suppose to have the IDE installed. Check out this link maybe I missed some thing. http://www.samsungdforum.com/guide/ you have to go to getting started and then 4.5 install guide. They don't have a 5.1 guide so I guess it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are a B2B developer then try downloading sdk from here:
   http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Devtools/SdkDownload

otherwise from here:
http://samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload

2. Also install the Virtual Box and and its extension pack from here:
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
3. Make sure to download and mount the Emulator on virtual box.
   **Also, as per mentioned by Samsung you must have Windows XP Service Pack 2 or higher**.
4. Set the path for Chrome for web debugging. Also set the Emulator settings.
   Here is the link to the Samsung Guide:
   http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/
5. List of files after extracting the sdk:
   [image]

Hope these resources will help you little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
New > Other (or simply Ctrl + N) and find "Samsung Smart TV" on the list. There are some types of apps you can create for Samsung TV: Web app, Caph or PNaCl